# Suppose for every $x \in X$, the sequence $(T^n(x))$ admits a convergent subsequence, prove $(T^n(x))$ converge to a fixed point of $T$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let  $(X, \|\cdot \|)$ be a normed space and $T: X \rightarrow X$ (non linear) such that
>
> 1. $\left \| T(x) - T(y)\right \| \leq \left \| x-y \right \|$ for all $x,y \in X$;
> 2. $\left \| T(x) - T^{2}(x)\right \| < \left \| x-T(x) \right \|$ if $x \ne T(x)$;
> 3. For every $x \in X$, the sequence $(T^n(x))$  admits a convergence subsequence.
>
> Prove that for every $x \in X$, $(T^n(x))$ converge to a fixed point of $T$.

Proof:  1). First we need to show that for every $x \in X$, $(T^n(x))$ is convergent (How?)

2).  Suppose we have that for every $x \in X$, $(T^n(x))$ is convergent to some $y \in X$. We have to show that $T(y)=y$.

If $(T^n(x)) \longrightarrow y$,  then for each $\varepsilon>0$ there exist $N_{\varepsilon} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$ \|T^n(x)-y \|<\varepsilon \quad \text{for all $n\geq N_{\varepsilon}$.}$$

To see that $T(y)=y$,  let $\varepsilon>0$ be given, then if $n\geq N_{\varepsilon}$ we have 
\begin{align*}
 \|T(y)-y \|&=\|T(y)-T^{n+1}(x)+T^{n+1}(x)-y \| \\
 &\leq \|T(y)-T^{n+1}(x) \| + \|T^{n+1}(x)-y \| \\
 &\leq \|T^n(x)-y \| + \|T^{n+1}(x)-y \| \\
 &\leq \varepsilon/2 + \varepsilon/2 \\
 &= \varepsilon.
\end{align*}

Could you please help me to prove that the sequence is convergent? Or just any idea ( I know from part  3 that it must be the limit)

Edit: This proposition is false as you can see from Robert's comment.
Edit 2: I forgot I used $\leq$ instead of < in $2.$ so ill open the question again

Comment: If you can show that the sequence is cauchy, and you already know it has a convergent subsequence then that shows that your original sequence converges. Hope that helps

Comment: But $X$ is not complete.

Comment: I know but there is a theorem that says the following: Let (M,d) be any metric space, with $x_n$ being Cauchy, if $x_n$ has a convergent subsequence to a limit x, then the sequence $x_n$ converges to x as well. Also even if X is not complete you can still have a cuachy sequence that converges. Recall that a metric space is complete if every cauchy sequence in the metric space converges in the metric space.

Comment: Does not 1 automatically imply 2? Would not a rotation in $\Bbb R^2$ be a counterexample then? It is linear though.

Comment: I dont think so.

Comment: Let $y= T(x)$. Then you have $$\|T(x)-T^2(x)\| = \|T(x)-T(y)\| \le \|x-y\| = \|x-T(x)\|.$$ No?

Answer (score 3):

It's not true.  Try $X = \mathbb R$, $T(x) = 1 - x$.

Comment: What if $T$ is non linear? I checked that your operator satisfies 1,2,3 but $T$ is linear in this example.

Comment: It's affine, not linear.

Answer (score 1):

If you want some non affine counter example you can take $T(x)=1-|x|$ with $X=\mathbb{R}$. Clearly $|T(x)-T(y)|=|1-|x|-1+|y||=||y|-|x||\leq|x-y|$. Then you can compute $T^n(x)$.